# Do these Feats + Paladin Relentless Avenger = Redundant?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, class-feature, paladin

Forgive the awkwardness of this question, I'm not sure where to put it or how to flag this, as it's not pertaining to rulings but rather interactions.

I'm currently using a Vengeance Paladin that wields a Maul/Warhammer who has just unlocked the level 7 ability Relentless Avenger.

It allows me to move up to half my speed (15ft) without provoking opportunity attacks of my own immediately after I hit a creature with an opportunity attack and as part of the opportunity attack. (Movement happens before the creature continues to move out of my reach)

Then I sat my sights on Sentinel, which allows me to make opportunity attacks even if that creature 'Disengage's before it tries to flee, and whenever I do hit a creature with an opportunity attack, it's speed immediately becomes 0.
Opportunity Attack = target's speed 0 and free 15 ft instant movement.

That's great...but then I noticed there are VERY few ways to gain opportunity attacks aside from creatures moving out of my attack range.  With me being the Paladin that smashes in creatures' skulls, very few things move through my range; and instead head right for me.  I see that the Polearm Master feat grants opportunity attacks when a creature ENTERS your reach, in addition to if they ever leave your reach....but that would involve switching to polearms after 7 levels of building a blunt instrument legacy.

Is this worth it?  Do any of these combination of feats + abilities cancel each other out or make the other redundant, or is the end result as powerful as I think it may be?

Comment: What does "cancel each other out" or "redundant" mean here? It sounds like you're saying something like "I have all this opportunity attack based stuff, but it's hard to generate opportunity attacks." And then I can't tell what question you're actually trying to ask.

Comment: I'm asking if these 3 abilities pair well together, or does having one or all of them become redundant.  Do any of them interact in an awkward way that might make taking one of the above feats meaningless.  I'm trying to get as much oomph out of Relentless Avenger as possible, utilizing available means of gaining more Opportunity Attack options.

Answer (score 5):

You say "... there are VERY few ways to gain opportunity attacks aside from creatures moving out of my attack range." Yes, as far as I can see there are exactly 2:

> 1. You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile
>      creature that you can see moves out of your reach. (PHB p.195)
> 2. **Polearm Master** While you are wielding a glaive, halberd, pike, or quarterstaff, other creatures provoke an opportunity attack
>      from you when they enter your reach. (PHB p.168)

Of these, Polearm Master will give you the most reliable chances for opportunity attacks; otherwise, they simply do not come up that often. Absent Polearm Master, suffering an opportunity attack is **voluntary**, the creature must choose to leave your reach without Disengaging (unless you have Sentinel). As you say, most creatures who enter your reach will only leave it in a body bag.

My advice to you, "Put away your maul, it is time to give up childish things"; Polerm Master will virtually guarantee you an opportunity attack against every opponent. If you really want to bludgeon things, you can use the quarterstaff 2 handed for a respectable 1d8 damage or use it one handed and start carrying a shield.

Comment: Take note that the Sentinel line you quoted does NOT grant you opportunity attacks.  It says you may use your reaction to make a (non opportunity) melee weapon attack.
I thought this was the case as well until I took a closer look.

Comment: Good point. Will edit.